# jQuery Sortable, horizontally snap to grid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a form that generates divs wrapped in an li. I have made this list sortable.

I also need to find a way for the li to indent 40px to the right (visually making it a child of the li above). If an li is indented, then the next li has the option to be indented by 80px. This will be used to create a menu tree.

I have the form working, here is the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/BMX4J/11/

I have no idea how to do the horizontal snapping though, please help

The purpose of this is to mimic the functionality found in Wordpress - WPAdmin/Appearance/Menus/Pages

Please ask if you have any questions. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Nested Sortable jQuery Plugin](http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/) is a nice place to start.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been getting nowhere on this, I'll check it out :)